# Azure deployment via SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-sdk-.net

I'm running out of time to get this done, but I just can't seem to find my issue.

I'm trying to deploy an ARM template that creates a new MCA subscription. The template works when deployed via Azure PowerShell, but when using the Azure SDK it gives the following error:

> Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: 'Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Subscription/aliases/devtestdeployasp22' referenced in output is not defined in the template. Please specify resource identifier and api version if the resource is outside of the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#reference for usage details.'.'

```
var subscription = azure.Deployments
            .Define("deployment_temp")
            .WithNewResourceGroup("temprg", Region.USEast)
            .WithTemplate(Utils.GetArmTemplate("<path_to_file_removed_for_privacy>"))
            .WithParameters("{}")
            .WithMode(Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Models.DeploymentMode.Incremental)
            .Create();
```

The template used with this contains:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-08-01/managementGroupDeploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "subscriptionAliasName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Provide a name for the alias. This name will also be the display name of the subscription."
      }
    },
    "billingScope": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "<Removed>",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Provide the full resource ID of billing scope to use for subscription creation."
      }
    },
    "mgName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "mg-mission-default-dev",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "management group name"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "mgId": "[concat('Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/',parameters('mgName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "scope": "[variables('mgId')]",
      "name": "[parameters('subscriptionAliasName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Subscription/aliases",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "properties": {
        "workLoad": "Production",
        "displayName": "[parameters('subscriptionAliasName')]",
        "billingScope": "[parameters('billingScope')]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "subscriptionID": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Subscription/aliases', parameters('subscriptionAliasName'))).subscriptionId]"
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, or even an alternate path I could take but the goal is to create a new MCA subscription (with some resources) using C#.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the Subscription ID by using tenantResourceId -

**tenantResourceId** - Returns the unique identifier for a resource deployed at the tenant level.

```
      "outputs": {
        "subscriptionId": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "[reference(tenantResourceId('Microsoft.Subscription/aliases', parameters('subscriptionAliasName'))).subscriptionId]"
        }
      }
```

Please refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#tenantresourceid).